# DAX - How to lookup and return a value from another table based on 2 possible lookups

Tags: powerbi, dax, lookup

I have 2 tables, one has a ton of fields so I didn't copy it all but the 2 fields in the big table that I'm working with are "Item Number" and "Item Description". The smaller table is pictured below.

ItemData table
ItemNumber
ItemDescription
Entities
ProductLines

The two tables are not related; I need to have a column in the big table named "Entity" where I lookup the item number or the item description (if the item number is missing) and return what Entity is associated. If both fields are empty then return "NONE".

My current code is below and it works sometimes which doesn't make sense because the code isn't correct, I know.  I also can't get it to look at one field if the other is blank which is why that part of the code has been deleted.

```
Entity = LOOKUPVALUE(ItemData[Entities],ItemData[Item Number],Page1_1[Item Number],"None")
```

Here is what I want it to say in DAX - Entity = if itemNumber is not null then use item number to retrieve the entity name, otherwise use the itemdescription to find the entity.

Here is what I would like to see:

Item number = "123"

Item Description = "Sunshine"

Entity = "Florida"

I can pull item number and description from the big table. I just need to match those with the small table to get the entity.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an if statement:

```
Entity = IF(ISEMPTY(ItemData[Item Number]) then 
LOOKUPVALUE(ItemData[Entities],ItemData[Item Description],Page1_1[Item Description]) else
LOOKUPVALUE(ItemData[Entities],ItemData[Item Number],Page1_1[Item Number]))
```

Comment: Please confirm if this helped you by setting to answered